# how to increment nvarchar type in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Tab1 with one of the column being `ID` of`Nvarchar(80)` [MSSQL] . I would like to have a variable as with initial value= `00100000` and then increment it by `00100001`,`00100002`,`00100003` and so on .later use it to fetch tab1.id from this variable in a loop. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Don't. Use an int identity column instead. A user designed auto increment column is bound to fail. I'm not even sure legends like Aaron Bertrand or Martin Smith can write a reliable auto increment column using simple sql without using identity or sequence.

Answer (score 5):

I'll start by saying that if you want an easy-to-increment variable, `NVARCHAR` isn't exactly the way to go; but I'll also assume you have a reason for doing this.

That being said, incrementing the value is as easy as:

```
SELECT CAST(<column_name> AS INT) + 1 FROM Tab1;
```

To insert the value with leading zeroes, you're going to need to do some concatenation:

```
SELECT '00' + CAST(CAST(<column_name AS INT) + 1 AS NVARCHAR(80)) FROM Tab1;
```

Just FYI, SQL Server will automatically try to convert the `NVARCHAR` value to an `INTEGER` value when you try adding 1, so you could technically shorten this to:

```
SELECT '00' + CAST(<column_name> + 1 AS NVARCHAR(80));
```

If you're eventually expecting to reach values which override those two leading zeroes, you're also going to need to take that into account later on. There are several ways that you could do this.  Among the simplest:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST(<column_name> + 1 AS NVARCHAR(80)),8);
```

Comment: This is not threas safe at all. Multiple users executing this code in the same time will get the same numbers.

Comment: @ATC Obviously.  The OP already got one comment about using an `IDENTITY` column, and also didn't say anything about how many users were going to be incrementing this data simultaneously, if at all.  I even started by saying that this isn't the way to go; but incrementation of an `NVARCHAR` remains possible, if unadvisable, so my only goal here was to answer the OP's actual question.

Comment: I would suggest using a calculated column based on an identity column. Simple, clean,  and thread safe.

Comment: @ATC I would most definitely invite you to post that as an answer, and I would also hope that it would be accepted.